# How to tell doctrine to not persist relationships

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have following use case:

```
    // In one part of code
    foreach ($order->getAssignedItems() as $existingItem) {
        // Do something
    }

    // In another part of code
    $existingItem = $this->em->find(AssignedOrderItem::class, $removeId);
    $this->em->remove($existingItem);
    $this->em->flush();

    // A lot later, after 4 events
    $order->setPrice(1234, 'USD);
    $this->em->prsist($order);
    $this->em->flush();
```

During the second flush doctrine finds the deleted assignedItems and throws exception:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship Order#assignedItems that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AssignedOrderItem. 
To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping.
```

Except I don't want it to persist, I just deleted those entities.
In fact I don't want doctrine to attempt to persist any toMany relationships.

How can I force doctrine to just ignore `assignedItems` when updating `Order`?

Comment: 3 ideas comes to my mind : First, try adding an "unset($existingItem);". Second, if $order has been fetched before the first flush, try $this->em->refresh($order); Third, check if the assignedItem is still in your collection and remove it


As a general rule of thumb, I suggest you try to not have more than a Flush() per http request. It will prevent you from facing those kind of issues

Comment: @Mouke Will a refresh also reload `toMany` relationships? It feels very inefficient if it does. Unless there is a way to specify to refresh the relationship.

Comment: Can't say for sure, my guess would be : It depends of how you mapped your relation (the "fetch" parameter), it would refresh it to its initial state.

Answer (score 1):

I would likely remove the item from the collection on order and add cascade persist to the association in your Order class.

Comment: Yes this is how it should be done.  However, a more detailed answer will be more likely to get up-votes.

Comment: The issue is that function that removes that entity does not even know about `order`. It just removes the entity based on its `id` and ignores any relationships.